# After Insert trigger update same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

Trying a trigger in SQL Server for the first time. Please help as I am getting error message and I am unsure of the correct syntax:

I want to update a specific column (Col_2) in the same table after (or before) insert if it is NULL; based on another inserted column's value (Col_1). I want to update Col_2 to 'A' or 'B' as per below.

below is the code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trg_1 
   ON Table_1
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    if INSERTED.[Col_2] is null
    begin

    if  left(INSERTED.[Col_1],3) = 'bud'
    begin
    update Table_1
    set [Col_2] = 'B'
    from INSERTED
    where INSERTED.[Col_ID] = Table_1.[Col_ID]
    end
    else
    begin

    update Table_1
    set [Col_2] = 'A'
    from INSERTED
    where INSERTED.[Col_ID] = Table_1.[Col_ID]
   end
   end  

END
```

Any help would be appreciated.

The error is:
The multi-part identifier INSERTED.[Col_2] could not be bound.

Comment: The official documentation explains how to reference inserted and deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *first* problem is that your `IF` references a column, however, to reference a column you need a `FROM`, and you have no `FROM`. As such `INSERTED.[Col_1]` has no context; no table `INSERTED` is defined so it's impossible to reference its column `Col_1`.

Though the syntax you have also used *assumes* that an `INSERT` only ever contains 1 row, which isn't true; an `INSERT` can contain 0+ rows. What would you expect the above to do if `inserted` contains *many* rows; if a single row contains the value `bud` would you want *all* the rows to `UPDATE` with the letter `B`?

What you need to do is just use a "simple" `UPDATE...FROM` statement:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER Trg_1 ON dbo.Table_1
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE T1
    SET Col_2 = CASE WHEN i.Col_2 LIKE 'bud%' THEN 'B' ELSE 'A' END
    FROM inserted i
        JOIN dbo.Table_1 T1 ON i.Col_ID = T1.Col_ID;

END;
```

Answer (score 4):

I would strongly suggest you don't use a trigger at all, and instead just use a computed column

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table_1
ADD Col_2 AS (IIF(Col_1 LIKE 'bud%', 'B', 'A'));
-- alternatively
ADD Col_2 AS (UPPER(LEFT(Col_1, 1)));
```

Comment: Thanks alot for this answer, I never considered it.